# Facebook automatic Birthday wish

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, message

i want to write a script which send automatically an friend birthday wishes. My base idea was to write a php script which called every day by a cronjob. All solution which i found was deprecated by facebook.

Actually my idea is to export my facebook calender and let a script run over the "export-list" that import the birthdays into a database. Then I have to call every day the javascript that popup a send-dialog if someone have birthday. But that is not comfortable.

Did somebody know a better solution?

Comment: The _only_ way to send private message is via the dialog. (And before you start thinking about making automatic timeline posts – that is not allowed.)

Comment: hm oke, i though i saw a software offer which support to send a private message with an delay.

Comment: Do you know a better way to get the birthday dates from my friends?

Comment: You won’t be able to get friend’s birthdays from the API in any case, unless they become users of your app as well and give your app permission.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the friends' birthdays anymore, because all the `friends_*` permissions have been removed with v2.0 of the Graph API. Only if they are also users of the same app and give the app the permissions.